# Angular requires Zone.js polyfill. with system js i am facing this issue

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs

I am facing this error when I installed angular4 with systemjs and ASP.NET MVC4.
I tried to fix this issue by commenting the code

```
"throw new error('Angular requires Zone.js prolyfill.')"
```

in node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js.But nothing worked out.

My exact problem was.

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Angular requires Zone.js prolyfill.
>       at new NgZone (core.umd.js:3805)
>       at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone (core.umd.js:4524)
>       at eval (core.umd.js:4569)
>       at

Please help me if anyone knows how to resolve this issue.

Dependencies i used in my cshtml file

```
<script src="~/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/zone.js@0.8.4/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script src="~/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('app').catch(function (err)
    {
       console.error(err);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check that path with the version number from `node_modules`. It might not physically contain that version number in the file structure, and isn't loading causing the error. Verify directly, but the correct path should be as follows:

```
<script src="~/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
```

If you need to manage the version you can do that via `package.json` and `npm install` like the following:

```
"zone.js": "0.8.4"
```